# Evaluate a Recommender System based on the data between two months

Tags: training, recommender-system, ab-test

currently my company's planning to use a new Recommender tool/library for a book website, and now we want to compare the result between these two tools (both of the tool use Universal Recommender System, an algorithm work on **multi-events** like **Purchase, Wishlist, View**,...). My manager said we won't have enough resources for the A/B test or online survey, so we want to do an offline evaluation.

Our idea is to run these tools on the data of a month (for example October ~ **train data**), and then compare these predictions' results to the real data of the next month (November ~ **test data**).
For example:

- Prediction Result of Tool A: u1 (user1): [i1 (item1), i3, i4], u2:....
- Prediction Result of Tool B u1: [i2, i4, i5], u2:...
- Real data on November: u1: {Purchase: [i4,i5], Wishlist: [i3], View: [i2]}, u2:...

Now how to evaluate which tool is better in this situation?
My idea is, if a tool has a **"hit"** (predict the right item), then give that tool some scores, which are equal to **1 x Number of Hit Items** for **Purchase**, **0.8x**... for **Wishlist**, and so on. In the end, I will calculate the **sum of all events** and **all users** for a tool and them compare.

In the above example, the score will be

- Tool A: 0.8x1 (i3 hit at **Wishlist** event) + 1x1 (i4 hit at **Purchase** event) = 1.8
- Tool B: 0.5x1 (i2 hit at **View** event) + 1x2 (i4, i5 both hit at **Purchase** event) = 2.5

Is my method ok? Or is there any good method out there for a Multi-event recommender system like this? Because when I read some research on the internet, most of them are only for 1-event only like rating, and purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because tool A and B might result in recommendations with different numbers of items, using ratio is more suitable than the actual score.

1. calculate hit ratio for each one

   eg. hit ratio = 1 * ( Purchase hit count / total recommended count ) + 0.8 * ( Wishlist hit count / total recommended count )
2. use an **average of hit ratio** to evaluate recommendation performance